# Having problems reading in data from file and using it on the fly using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, config

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will send an email if a service goes into a stopped state. I would like to be able to read the email configuration from another file.

Email configuration file:

**.\emailconfig.conf**

```
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.company.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "usera"
$emailSmtpPass = "passwordb"

$emailFrom = "userA@company.com"
$emailTo = "userB@company.com"
$emailcc= "userC@company.com"
```

And this is what I have so far in the PowerShell script:

**.\emailservicecheck.ps1**

```
$A = Get-Service "Service B"

if ($A.Status -eq "Stopped") {
    Get-Content emailconfig.conf | Out-String

    $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($emailFrom, $emailTo)
    $emailMessage.Cc.Add($emailcc)
    $emailMessage.Subject = "subject"
    #$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true  # true or false depends
    $emailMessage.Body = Get-Service "Service B" | Out-String

    $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($emailSmtpServer, $emailSmtpServerPort)
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $False
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($emailSmtpUser, $emailSmtpPass);
    $SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)
}
```

The script works if I enter the text from the email config file into the script but I cannot seem to be able to read in the data from the file on the fly and get the script to work. It errors out and says that my variables are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Mark already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976008/1630171), `Get-Content emailconfig.conf | Out-String` will just output the content of the file, it won't define the variables in your code. For that you'd need to [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) the file, which requires a file with the extension ".ps1".

If you want to stick with a simple config file format I'd recommend changing the file to something like this:

```
emailSmtpServer = smtp.company.com
emailSmtpServerPort = 587
emailSmtpUser = usera
emailSmtpPass = passwordb

emailFrom = userA@company.com
emailTo = userB@company.com
emailcc = userC@company.com
```

And importing it into a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) via [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-3.0):

```
$cfg = Get-Content emailconfig.conf | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

The data in the hashtable can be accessed via dot-notation (`$cfg.emailFrom`) as well as via the index operator (`$cfg['emailFrom']`), so your code would have to look somewhat like this:

```
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($cfg.emailFrom, $cfg.emailTo)
$msg.Cc.Add($cfg.emailcc)
$msg.Subject = 'subject'
$msg.Body    = Get-Service 'Service B' | Out-String

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($cfg.emailSmtpServer, $cfg.emailSmtpServerPort)
$smtp.EnableSsl   = $false
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($cfg.emailSmtpUser, $cfg.emailSmtpPass)
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: thats actually what i did in the end but took a while to find it and try it :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for, (I think) are [`.psd1` files](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PowerShell-Configuration-Data/#powershell-data-file-psd1). I personally prefer them (along with JSON) over the other configuration formats. The link I'm referring to also describes other well-known formats and how to use them in PowerShell.

In short, module manifests work as follows:

**configuration.psd1**

```
@{
    SmtpServer = "";
    MailFrom = "";
    Auth = @{
        User = "";
        Pass = "";
    };
}
```

**Script.ps1**

```
$mailConfig = Import-LocalizedData -BaseDirectory C:\ -FileName configuration.psd1
$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $$mailConfig.mailFrom , $mailConfig.mailTo )
```

Comment: .psd1 files are manifests for PowerShell modules, and `Import-LocalizedData` is a cmdlet that "imports language-specific data into scripts and functions based on the UI culture that is selected for the operating system". I don't recommend abusing either of them for config file import. Just because something can be done doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it.

Comment: As we don't know if OP is writing a module, it's not sure, if it's really _abusing_ of module manifests. I like that way, because it uses built in features and is less abusing than executing text out of .conf files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do is include some script from another file. This can be done by [dot sourcing](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/02/02/exploring-dot-sourcing-in-powershell.aspx), however the file needs to be saved as a .ps1 file, you can't use .conf.

You'd do it as follows (in place of your existing `Get-Content`) line:

```
. .\emailconfig.ps1
```

Assuming the file is kept in the current working directory of the script.

Your script wasn't working because

```
get-content emailconfig.conf | Out-String
```

Was returning the contents of that file to the output pipeline, rather than including it in the script and executing it.

Comment: i want the information in the conf file as easy as possible to read for a none technical person. So they can fill out there information as needed. So the text file should be configurable however the powershell script will not be configurable.

Comment: Then you should go with the other answer.  By dot sourcing someone could modify the "conf" file to include any code they like and that code would be executed by your script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood correctly what you want.

If you want to use variables from external file, you need to dot source your external script, for example, create a file named variables.ps1 and put in the same folder
In the beginning of the main script use

```
. .\variables.ps1
```

If you are after expanding variables that are in external file to ues as an email template please do as following:

```
$HTMLBody = get-content "yourfilepath" | Foreach-Object {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)}
```

This will expand all variables and put it in the $HTMLBody variable
Then use:

```
$emailMessage.Body = (ConvertTo-Html -body $HTMLBody)
```